# Hibernate Criteria and Count Column

Tags: hibernate, count, subquery, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to return an entity with a column that has the count of another table that is a one to many relation. I want to do this using hibernate criteria, not HQL.

```
select p.*, (select count(*) from child where child.parentid = p.id) as LEVELS
from parent p
```

Comment: Is your "where" clause supposed to be a "from"?

Comment: Thanks fixed that syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it to work doing this.  Not very dynamic but it will work.

```
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "LEVEL")
    @Formula(value="(SELECT count(*) FROM BadgeLevels bl WHERE bl.badgeid = this_.id)")
        public long getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If the parent entity also contains a list of children (bi-directional association), you can use criteria to return the count of children as follows:

```
    Criteria criteria = hibernateSessionHelper.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Parent.class);

    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
    projList.add(Projections.countDistinct("children.id"));
    projList.add(Property.forName("field1").group());
    projList.add(Property.forName("field2").group());
    projList.add(Property.forName("field3").group());
    .
    .
    .
    criteria.createAlias("children", "children", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);

    criteria.setProjection(projList);

    List<Object[]> results = crit.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it by some kind of projection.

See the [tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection) on Hibernate projections. You are probably interested in the `sqlProjection` method in the [Projections](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html) class for the sub-query.

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Parent.class, "p") 
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("field1"))
        .add(Projections.property("field2"))
        .add(Projections.property("field3"))
        .add(Projections.sqlProjection("select count(*) from child where child.parentid = p.id"), new String[] {"LEVELS"}, new Type[] {Hibernate.INTEGER})
    ).list();
```

Comment: I am going to try that but is there anyway not to use raw sql, and use a detached query somehow?

Comment: The tricky part seems to be that, your `count` depends on another relation. If you use the Hibernate [Association](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html) mappings, then you can map a list of Child objects and just use the Java `size` method.

Comment: See my other answer for the associations method.

Comment: That original project gave me

select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            select
                count(*) 
            from
                badgelevels bl 
            where
                bl.badgeid = b.id 
            from
                CISCO.BADGES this_ 
            where
                this_.ACTIVE=? ) 
        where
            rownum <= ?

Comment: How can I return the rest of the columns from Parent.class with the count?  Am I missing a projection?

Comment: You can add the additional columns by chaining calls on the `projectionList`. I've amended my original answer for this.

Comment: Yea but how do you do it in one call because I might add more properties in the future and don't want to type out 20 columns to bring back.

Answer (score 0):

Define an object field mapping like below. Then when you query your Parent objects, each object should have a field of type list called children that you can call `size` on.

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set name="children">
        <key column="parentId" 
            not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="Child"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="Child">
    <id name="id" column="childId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
</class>
```

Comment: I am returning a list of parents, and I don't want to return all the join childs of that object.  I just want the count of the children with the parent columns.